# change color of disableProperty() function / how disable clicking on Stage

Tags: java, javafx

Hello it's my first ask on stack. I got problem with `disablebleProperty()` function. It make my `Stage` dark grey and it's looking terrible. How can I disable clicking on my stage when some `Task` is running like in the following code:

```
buttonName.setOnAction((event) -> {

    Task task = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            try {

                buttonName.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
                buttonName.getScene().getRoot().disableProperty().bind(primaryStage.getScene().cursorProperty().isEqualTo(Cursor.WAIT));

                anotherFunction();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                buttonName.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
});
```

Comment: Disabled controls are usually grayed out to indicate they cannot be interacted with - this is almost always a desirable feature. You should probably not disable the entire stage, but only the relevant parts (i.e. the button and some input/output fields).

Answer (score 1):

You should not update the ui from a thread other than the JavaFX application thread. Since `Task.call` is run on a seperate thread, you shouldn't run the code there. Also binding to the curser property instead of also calling `setDisable(false)` seems like a bad idea, especially since you never unbind the property.

Use the event handler for `onSucceeded` for handling the successful completion of the task. (`onFailed` and `onCanceled` are available for different ways your task could finish, which won't happen in the code snippet you posted.)

```
buttonName.setOnAction((event) -> {
    buttonName.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
    buttonName.setDisable(true);
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            try {
                anotherFunction();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> {
        buttonName.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        buttonName.setDisable(true);
    });
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
});
```

To disable other controls in the scene too, you could instead disable/reenable the root of the scene:

```
buttonName.getScene().getRoot().setDisable(newValue);
```

To prevent the grayed out look JavaFX applies on the disabled controls (setting opacity to 0.4) you could apply a different opacity with higher precedence e.g. by setting the opacity from code

```
buttonName.setOpacity(1);
```

or by applying a style using a custom stylesheet

#### style.css

```css
*:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
```

#### scene initialisation

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
```